Seem to be missing a DLL but I can't seem to find any leads. Assistance appreciated for an odd setup
Installed Python successfully. The current installation version is 3.10.6 as per the console.
Installed Git 2.45.2-64 successfully.
Went to GitHub - lshqqytiger/stable-diffusion-webui-amdgpu: Stable Diffusion web UI and installed SD for AMD GPUs. Entered the gitclone command and it downloaded everything to an external drive.
Edited the webui-user.bat file to include paths to Python and to skip Nvidia Cuda.
Everything ran and loaded to 127.0.0:7860. Downloaded some cpts and tried to render my first image. SD hung. Every time I restart now (full machine restart 2ce) I get the following error:
venv "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"

Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug 1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]

Version: v1.9.3-amd-26-g50d3cf78

Commit hash: 50d3cf7852cfe07bd562440246202d8925be98a4

no module 'xformers'. Processing without...

no module 'xformers'. Processing without...

No module 'xformers'. Proceeding without it.

E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\distributed.py:258: LightningDeprecationWarning: \pytorch_lightning.utilities.distributed.rank_zero_only` has been deprecated in v1.8.1 and will be removed in v2.0.0. You can import it from `pytorch_lightning.utilities` instead.`

rank_zero_deprecation(

Launching Web UI with arguments: --skip-torch-cuda-test

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\launch.py", line 48, in <module>

main()

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\launch.py", line 44, in main

start()

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\launch_utils.py", line 689, in start

import webui

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\webui.py", line 13, in <module>

initialize.imports()

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\initialize.py", line 35, in imports

from modules import shared_init

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\shared_init.py", line 8, in <module>

from modules.zluda import initialize_zluda

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\zluda.py", line 6, in <module>

import onnxruntime as ort

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>

raise import_capi_exception

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>

from onnxruntime.capi._pybind_state import ExecutionMode # noqa: F401

File "E:\AI\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\_pybind_state.py", line 32, in <module>

from .onnxruntime_pybind11_state import * # noqa

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing onnxruntime_pybind11_state: The specified module could not be found.

Press any key to continue . . .

I've done a dozen hours of research all night. Poured through the Python files. Added paths to my Environmental Variables. Still stuck. If anyone has any ideas and why it's suddenly broken, I'd be appreciative.
